# Rails Paperclip dynamic styles - avoid scaling SVG

Tags: ruby-on-rails, svg, mongoid, paperclip

I want to provide my styles parameter with some lambda that checks if the file is an SVG file, *scale it properly or not at all*, I would like to communicate with the model as I do with all my other images, as when i render them (@image.image(:thumb). Is this possible?

Right now I attach my file  as:

```
has_mongoid_attached_file :image,
            :path => 'app/assets/images/library/:id/:style.:extension',
            :styles => {:thumb => "216x162#", :medium => "400x300#", :scenario => "700x525#"},
            :url => '/assets/library/:id/:style.:extension'
```

I've read about dynamic styles and did some trial and error with not success. My thought was that someone perhaps already have done this.

Answer (score 1):

correct me if I misunderstood your question.

Please check https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#dynamic-styles which says you can provide an lambda with attachment as argument of this lambda.

Inside the block you can use `attachment.instance.#{any instance method of model}`.

Comment: No, you're right, I forgot to close the question, figured it out. Thanks anyway. :)